# Yii2 Modal close button not working with JQuery 3.6.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, modal-dialog

I just updated my JQuery.js to version 3.6.0 and all of a sudden some of my functions stopped working, eg my modal close buttons don't work anymore. I am using Yii2 ver2.0.45. I was previously using JQuery 3.4.4 which was working very well. Any suggestions/solutions will be appreciated. Here is my modal code block.

```
<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'title' => '<h4></h4>',
        'id' => 'modal',
        'titleOptions' => [
            'style' => 'background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        ],
        'closeButton' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right',
        ],
        'options' => [
            'tabindex' => false // important for Select2 to work properly
        ],
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
        // keeps from closing modal with esc key or by clicking out of the modal
        // user must click cancel or X to close
        'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => false],
    ]);
    $contentDiv = "<div id='content'></div>";
    echo $contentDiv;
    Modal::end();
?>
```

Comment: You should also check the bootstrap version or browser version (is it compatible)

Comment: Thank you @user206 for pointing this out. Found out that my bootstrap.js@5.1.3 was higher than my botstrap.css therefore the errors with the jquery

Comment: Glad your problem was solved. Good luck.